# Making a schedule page using php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to make a schedule page, where I have an sql table called appointments which contains (id, name, date, time). I want to regroup data in this table in an html/css based table that all records of the same date are regrouped like the image shown below[image]

Then, I want this table to repeat itself but whis new data of a new date.
I have Another problem is the empty drop down list, where I tried to echo all dates in it, and the user select a date to view schedules.
The code am trying to edit it is in this link:

[See the last part of the tutorial](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/organizing-data-with-tables/)

And I have this piece of code:

```
    <?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)
?>
<div class="container">
<table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
                            Schedule               

              <th scope="row">
                    <form action="" method="submit">
                    <select name="Date" required class="form-control" id="Date">
    <option value="">Please Select Date</option>
    <?php $sql2="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die($sql2."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    while($rows2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rows2['date'] ?>"><?php echo $rows2['date'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Select Date" />
</form>
              </th>
              <td class="schedule-offset" colspan="2">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ?>
          <?php if(isset($_POST['Date'])){ ?>

          <?php
          $selectOpt = $_POST['Date'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint WHERE date=".$rows2['date'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)
?>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">
                          <?php while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>

                <?php echo $rows['time'] ?>
              </th>
              <td scope="row" id="scheduleDate">
                <?php echo $rows['name'] ?>
              </td>
              <td scope="row">
                <?php echo $rows['date'] ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php }?>
            <?php }?>
              <th scope="row">
                <time datetime="14:00">2:00 PM</time>
              </th>
              <td>
                <a href="speakers.html#tessa-harmon">
                  <h4>Tessa Harmon</h4>
                  Crafty Coding: Generating Knitting Patterns
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Summary:
I want to choose a date from drop down list, then all data of this particular list are shown in this type of html table. But I am having a problem with them both (fetching into drop down, and echo data into this type of table).

Comment: after query `$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)` causing the problem, remove it if you want to to fetch all records inside loop

Comment: i need a help to rewrite the html based code in the tutorial into php data shown in the same design of the table any help ? Yes I remove it but cant figure how to rewrite the code

Comment: you to do list is very long, for select, you have to fetch date records in `<option>` attribute then to fetch records against date and show, you need jquery change method along with Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I want to choose a date from drop down list

```
<select name="Date" required class="form-control" id="Date">
    <option value="">Please Select Date</option>
    <?php $sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rows['date'] ?>"><?php echo $rows['date'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

2) Then all data of this particular list are shown in this type of HTML table.

You need [jQuery Change function](https://api.jquery.com/change/) along with [Ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to fetch data and show against selected date

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Date").change(function(){
            var seldate =$(this).val();
            $("#scheduleDate").html(seldate);
            var dataString = 'seldate='+ seldate;
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getdata.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#Schedule").html(data);
                } 
            });
        });
});
```

Create `getdata.php`

```
<?php
    //Datebase Connection
    if($_POST['seldate']) {
        $selDate = $_POST['seldate'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint WHERE date='$selDate'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['name'] ?></td>
        <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['date'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } } ?>
```

And HTML table will look something like

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        Schedule
        <th scope="row">
            //Date Select HERE
        </th>
        <td class="schedule-offset" colspan="2" id="scheduleDate"></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="Schedule">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sir it is little bit complicated. Let me tell you something: number 1) code is good for me. Now O want to get the selected value from <select> and use it as a variable to generate a table without using scripts. Any help ? Please see my edited code

Comment: 2 things, first above solution will work out of the box if you follow the code and 2nd what you asked without using script, not possible

Comment: Sir I am sure that I tried all your code but nothing happened. See my new code

Comment: ok lets see if you follow the steps, lets say you have `main.php` it contains, `dropdown select` and `script` and exact copy of `HTML` table in answer, make sure you have jquery lib above the script, then create `getdata.php` on same path as `main.php` is and just put database connection in it and rest the of the code in answer and it should work

Comment: I am using dreamweaver how to get jquery library to it because in scripts language I have only something like that : <script language="javascript" ...> but can't add language="jquery"

Comment: Please sir see my new code, nothing is shown when selecting a date

Comment: this is wrong `$sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint WHERE date=".$rows2['date'];` its inside `isset` function so it should be `$sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint WHERE date=".$selectOpt;`

Comment: by the way with the approach in answer you will get result something like this http://shehary.com/stackoverflow/tablefetch/index.php, keep changing the dates and see the result, the way you wana do it will work but it's old school

Comment: I swear god I tried your method but nothing happened no data are shown. If you want send me your email to send you my working pages

Comment: file sent. I hope you can fix it. I send everything to you. Thank you.

Comment: OK now it works. But please can you explain why we used the script ?